# Wix - How to avoid BrowseDlg when install path could be obtained from registry

Tags: wix

I am writing a installer using wix to install my application. I would like to get the installation path from the registry, rather than allowing the user to choose from the BrowseDlg of WixUI_InstallDir. For that, I am doing a RegistrySearch and trying to get the value of InstallPath. My objective is that, if the InstallPath is found in the registry, I would like to skip the BrowseDlg alone during installation and if the InstallPath is not found, then display the BrowseDlg. How can I achieve this? Please advice.

Here is my code snippet -

```
<Product Name="$(var.ProductName)" Id="*"
           UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)"
           Language="1033" Codepage="1252"
           Version="$(var.ProductVersion)"
           Manufacturer="xxx" >

    <Package Id="*" Keywords="Installer" InstallerVersion="200"
             Comments="$(var.ProductName) - $(var.ProductVersion)"
             InstallPrivileges="elevated" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />
    <!--MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of $(var.ProductName) is already installed." /-->
    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="xxx.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />
    <Property Id="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <RegistrySearch Id='InstallLocation' Type='raw'
        Root='HKCU' Key='Software\xx\yy' Name='InstallPath' />
    </Property>
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir"/>
    <PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK35"/>
    <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLFOLDER" />
    <Property Id="MSIRESTARTMANAGERCONTROL" Value="Disable"/>
```

Edit1: With the above code in place, I could see from the installer logs that the INSTALLFOLDER property was set with the InstallPath value (read from the registry) during the AppSearch action, but still the BrowseDlg gets displayed during the installation. My understanding is that, the BrowseDlg should get displayed only when the value of INSTALLFOLDER is not set. Is it not the case? Please advice.